# Adding a JSON Response to a HighCharts Graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, highcharts

So I have a a csv file that is converted to a JSON using a python script and which is accessible by using "/data" at the end of my route. I want to be able to receive this JSON response and put in into a HighCharts graph however the response I'm receiving is a bunch of arrays in an object of an object and I'm having trouble being able to access the data.

Here is a sample of what my JSON object looks like:

```
{"sensor_data":{"class_label":[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0],"sample index":["sample0","sample1","sample2","sample3","sample4","sample5","sample6","sample7","sample8","sample9","sample10","sample11","sample12","sample13","sample14","sample15","sample16","sample17","sample18","sample19","sample20","sample21","sample22","sample23","sample24","sample25","sample26","sample27","sample28","sample29","sample30","sample31","sample32","sample33","sample34","sample35","sample36","sample37","sample38","sample39","sample40","sample41","sample42","sample43","sample44","sample45","sample46","sample47","sample48","sample49","sample50","sample51","sample52","sample53","sample54","sample55","sample56","sample57","sample58","sample59","sample60","sample61","sample62","sample63","sample64","sample65","sample66","sample67","sample68","sample69","sample70","sample71","sample72","sample73","sample74","sample75","sample76","sample77","sample78","sample79","sample80","sample81","sample82","sample83","sample84","sample85","sample86","sample87","sample88","sample89","sample90","sample91","sample92","sample93","sample94","sample95","sample96","sample97","sample98","sample99","sample100","sample101","sample102","sample103","sample104","sample105","sample106","sample107","sample108","sample109","sample110","sample111","sample112","sample113","sample114","sample115","sample116","sample117","sample118","sample119","sample120","sample121","sample122","sample123","sample124","sample125","sample126","sample127","sample128","sample129","sample130","sample131","sample132","sample133","sample134","sample135","sample136","sample137","sample138","sample139","sample140","sample141","sample142","sample143","sample144","sample145","sample146","sample147","sample148","sample149","sample150","sample151","sample152","sample153","sample154","sample155","sample156","sample157","sample158","sample159","sample160","sample161","sample162","sample163","sample164","sample165","sample166","sample167","sample168","sample169","sample170","sample171","sample172","sample173","sample174","sample175","sample176","sample177","sample178","sample179","sample180","sample181","sample182","sample183","sample184","sample185","sample186","sample187","sample188","sample189","sample190","sample191","sample192","sample193","sample194","sample195","sample196","sample197","sample198","sample199","sample200","sample201","sample202","sample203","sample204","sample205","sample206","sample207","sample208","sample209","sample210","sample211","sample212","sample213","sample214","sample215","sample216","sample217","sample218","sample219","sample220","sample221","sample222","sample223","sample224","sample225","sample226","sample227","sample228","sample229","sample230","sample231","sample232","sample233","sample234","sample235","sample236","sample237","sample238","sample239","sample240","sample241","sample242","sample243","sample244","sample245","sample246","sample247","sample248","sample249","sample250","sample251","sample252","sample253","sample254","sample255","sample256","sample257","sample258","sample259","sample260","sample261","sample262","sample263","sample264","sample265","sample266","sample267","sample268","sample269","sample270","sample271","sample272","sample273","sample274","sample275","sample276","sample277","sample278","sample279","sample280","sample281","sample282","sample283","sample284","sample285","sample286","sample287","sample288","sample289","sample290","sample291","sample292","sample293","sample294","sample295","sample296","sample297","sample298","sample299","sample300","sample301","sample302","sample303","sample304","sample305","sample306","sample307","sample308","sample309","sample310","sample311","sample312","sample313","sample314","sample315","sample316","sample317","sample318","sample319","sample320","sample321","sample322","sample323","sample324","sample325","sample326","sample327","sample328","sample329","sample330","sample331","sample332","sample333","sample334","sample335","sample336","sample337","sample338","sample339","sample340","sample341","sample342","sample343","sample344","sample345","sample346","sample347","sample348","sample349","sample350","sample351","sample352","sample353","sample354","sample355","sample356","sample357","sample358","sample359","sample360","sample361","sample362","sample363","sample364","sample365","sample366","sample367","sample368","sample369","sample370","sample371","sample372","sample373","sample374","sample375","sample376","sample377","sample378","sample379","sample380","sample381","sample382","sample383","sample384","sample385","sample386","sample387","sample388","sample389","sample390","sample391","sample392","sample393","sample394","sample395","sample396","sample397","sample398","sample399"],"sensor0":[0.8342509834222027,0.8040591737544392,0.6944042750266697,0.7836895305460438,0.7888353321633572,0.2406299291845031,0.4056446222233688,0.7147468237320453,0.5353416487380942,0.548196738900725,0.5203011391221466,0.7516346854539425,0.856897479464049,0.7836895305460438,0.8553526511086944,0.8217145616588485,0.1817267638536257,0.2549525422938068,0.5228048219125999,0.2309840283134481,0.7707008154675333,0.5461938504660493,0.6267369308550971,0.3058042606114584,0.017609762120689543,0.8186554619781937,0.8742282449649711,0.5558963397473439,0.6279780315314364,0.6243948636445962,0.9370265827781692,0.600202119588456,0.34497258154899746,0.8139441290527544,0.8728351342285425,0.7255970828169529,0.6619734799196021,0.7931962261862477,0.9900022030230928,0.6616952542423745,0.8994521718278122,0.4454142189113598,0.5429973752491887,0.7008021524732678,0.9934538277850494,0.8728351342285425,0.5493169859197086,0.9240495885324922,0.13329305460959673,0.3910162510987541,0.865991367976391,0.8571331734679286,0.7661508941807119,0.3661386633239368,0.7050742645265525,0.8126376841635325,0.9900022030230928,0.457280457747594,0.7413951873443472,0.6461430374327456,0.6104136944386439,0.7404885489907799,0.9370265827781692,0.25221801901382856,0.9027174122768274,0.5463259057847863,0.608390063478528,0.9011410595665064,0.7451292968363841,0.6212116969120911,0.9070883495126832,0.6267369308550971,0.6094329209784268,0.8466507329797839,0.6123472105605812,0.6492969892053877,0.5228048219125999,0.8630070341435948,0.9921556221857328,0.4694026131479279,0.4321558372537115,0.8186554619781937,0.2452730534118909,0.5806852304972248,0.4463181844890969,0.03117022528870461,0.582578909603501,0.6301478078950739,0.7526444037868796,0.6545975458612655,0.5906735762251086,0.9088819202472465,0.9875428113339848,0.6315113420725106,0.7008021524732678,0.3201179992261679,0.6995393868192927,0.7545444904282262,0.5976449009002688,0.8261297992960709,0.8261297992960709,0.6569065479873349,0.9769446559729712,0.9020215048719044,0.5429973752491887,0.8509366656033454,0.8034467378486213,0.6535157872845202,0.8334763292922207,0.5979679623241948,0.9230786255584088,0.9875428113339848,0.7314436380352776,0.7527599196897644,0.7164371987678253,0.5349063125564877,0.6785352221143449,0.7304615662856323,0.7782670395655239,0.6362355209574786,0.9203199879351556,0.7226803760344891,0.5908372785205473,0.6901546573851163,0.8588260425673215,0.09957427671585163,0.9089891698631442,0.9089891698631442,0.5689746790121009,0.7626327439430869,0.06279587056835045,0.5426350781980658,0.5426350781980658,0.5897821358236218,0.5216669318045457,0.7226803760344891,0.6362355209574786,0.5761365150423148,0.5909810486814845,0.5906735762251086,0.3189403072683662,0.6230339064332895,0.509650228808574,0.7147468237320453,0.7652398570176886,0.7983735803065884,0.7139926180272788,0.7302040510211433,0.7830341392298311,0.8139441290527544,0.5493169859197086,0.6974960316317865,0.7661508941807119,0.7778184764919785,0.9104946877423422,0.9769149328563096,0.7363188502642961,0.8104132844705834,0.8289485979100332,0.19980807737048745,0.2595532491974152,0.7888353321633572,0.9921556221857328,0.2903927712733632,0.5843295890599021,0.7304615662856323,0.7633816404253955,0.9104946877423422,0.9921556221857328,0.7151618846475077,0.5840913187344342,0.10408607314504914,0.6943705049398179,0.3685566916624784,0.9452105344733114,0.5806852304972248,0.21917473189392234,0.6955821606135237,0.9994756875868857,0.2065432020154392,0.7440290277877339,0.6458002240423756,0.7440290277877339,0.8721848841542321,0.6403523412672083,0.943605466715396,0.6943705049398179,0.13957706100930845,0.3999914242849606,0.5689746790121009,0.9863485108715232,0.7045672957780832,0.8480753123662816,0.884672971113442,0.9876612956671996,0.6661535207384663,0.8893234504022597,0.9294196421826122,0.7916599110709502,0.6691036031479298,0.4614151538873268,0.15861531839627507,0.015053024774653534,0.2543016971647206,0.1511921994574441,0.9994756875868857,0.4604409744687393,0.9769446559729712,0.4089252022237506,0.3468684941507011,0.7451292968363841,0.047070279720089266,0.23001052263735836,0.017609762120689543,0.2999351059742477,0.589242986067106,0.04925981828155557,0.5031815354341485,0.8791254131837124,0.22028312291647856,0.3633405651132341,0.44570418861617295,0.4089252022237506,0.13552373976490928,0.4403657886428181,0.1061715580172884,0.4698986722233266,0.5843295890599021,0.5461938504660493,0.8342509834222027,0.25221801901382856,0.9203199879351556,0.014224388292887637,0.6243948636445962,0.2627475752333104,0.39883102235234297,0.4665234526634825,0.8027231448329213,0.2514021874406174,0.2903927712733632,0.4522904006838488,0.21908834385814235,0.2232892599291859,0.24892157633170545,0.41420945689899424,0.23663190020199265,0.8509366656033454,0.268169102662174,0.16303394577063554,0.034106691977286774,0.5031815354341485,0.4010800906959512,0.4830357827001226,0.7363188502642961,0.2993638736474489,0.3483870171643594,0.5148818302563637,0.5140772526628589,0.2406299291845031,0.7916599110709502,0.33099288927038906,0.16531398680109166,0.4694026131479279,0.19582203872775486,0.09957427671585163,0.19980807737048745,0.2263029910252448,0.06279587056835045,0.2760061161069235,0.3013115781149882,0.2549525422938068,0.4262476870784353,0.39883102235234297,0.7302040510211433,0.4932001394518949,0.22028312291647856,0.5203011391221466,0.0259007336043674,0.4932001394518949,0.3393463540008431,0.3751049541649163,0.4665234526634825,0.3444912677498805,0.7717788781391197,0.4745395722894433,0.3751397984518733,0.4171165764715357,0.24892157633170545,0.007774581261955293,0.5140772526628589,0.8104132844705834,0.15675082389319786,0.4871265679536285,0.3189403072683662,0.8537103978778746,0.22210488921052574,0.1134176494876178,0.4010800906959512,0.16034213558940258,0.4056446222233688,0.08242937762035263,0.0341087770223687,0.26622206982972163,0.6535157872845202,0.4731597158660253,0.4892828912800582,0.5171490872286908,0.8051964146780597,0.0940218083382992,0.7526444037868796,0.7652398570176886,0.5349063125564877,0.8466507329797839,0.21908834385814235,0.08242937762035263,0.2701890952736837,0.33504543142086984,0.5979679623241948,0.3999914242849606,0.8677942678451326,0.4162642961213104,0.5123748433765994,0.284440941684605,0.21749064046722444,0.2756409701063435,0.8013405456953867,0.2155375876171517,0.4127776194515831,0.3186671800383177,0.21908834385814235,0.5192303954654396,0.4162642961213104,0.457280457747594,0.7139926180272788,0.7527599196897644,0.1489541419006888,0.10371459034344688,0.13329305460959673,0.04880192397550232,0.4454142189113598,0.1542844172307145,0.12646817833225066,0.30414323954286715,0.0749903221112711,0.04925981828155557,0.13957706100930845,0.3186671800383177,0.6569065479873349,0.7688348089897896,0.2263029910252448,0.4508723811048195,0.9104946877423422,0.047070279720089266,0.6362355209574786,0.3057214116837209,0.3058042606114584,0.0960004785645413,0.3822714321804582,0.4909315154992018,0.24472411203549504,0.7156744529365995,0.3057214116837209,0.2309840283134481,0.29341537927882266,0.03117022528870461,0.4399382636370685,0.3141646638099491,0.2514021874406174,0.2595532491974152,0.14023971553432354,0.21908834385814235,0.329235377962243,0.6266052664129459,0.4267101490302346,0.3910162510987541,0.4891055830547436,0.6619734799196021,0.10371459034344688,0.3710235237294053,0.3078650530464981,0.1817267638536257,0.4403657886428181,0.16303394577063554,0.8553526511086944,0.11364750100152733,0.24472411203549504,0.4871265679536285,0.21464674459654232,0.26770905856219884,0.33504543142086984,0.4034349365762077,0.15861531839627507,0.5123748433765994,0.4267101490302346,0.6616952542423745,0.4331504161846808,0.3393463540008431,0.3201179992261679,0.05913230519528556,0.3797777155678834],"sensor1":[0.7260813992742677,0.253135155172477,0.5957765709194961,0.03877962756957088,0.1744333489120683,0.1424777511908094,0.7273879895132506,0.6562098658346016,0.27359076844875285,0.33742624657900044,0.25586066805193985,0.20844785608786254,0.621303197065188,0.11644707970559864,0.26077703534208485,0.6706865590631278,0.6356661691054787,0.7657419322995629,0.7199266939240095,0.6100998000744899,0.23531622891019002,0.7491564369949893,0.6786617531216094,0.723343638607208,0.6478782281787702,0.6072264170433108,0.5487481598077378,0.723343638607208,0.6202636630625171,0.5680141340860324,0.7154768280461169,0.5794353192567437,0.01681592436749013,0.5989839599335605,0.5767946020456288,0.6748935500294461,0.6706865590631278,0.5734931643828036,0.383823045197604,0.9759952061825568,0.6682326890082187,0.08118174168806147,0.079431946838743,0.7489520627519083,0.7479687089872854,0.2569802675993931,0.5759411240079411,0.18019338897063156,0.07078623113142167,0.24385998054145064,0.6526223470334807,0.14536679338349956,0.2182816282092908,0.6394083885914137,0.7557117095433368,0.597211497357959,0.5367293158177581,0.17862894576004795,0.3949563244602505,0.033907864699883265,0.5780030558939503,0.5654403607250189,0.2060239999489869,0.4449509190474525,0.25457364913505776,0.14652719602434394,0.6451312350889868,0.6312147419553418,0.16398904075526097,0.651144314958331,0.11479457620694232,0.2603923540467256,0.6654734698384653,0.7197958724177218,0.22296754837248967,0.17342653871012992,0.7459991836649209,0.4156151233911337,0.004605091264255457,0.7493075914703463,0.5876800246438066,0.8686302391733645,0.6727554860109296,0.10973740154345267,0.16398904075526097,0.715089921590326,0.11079876627933982,0.7258185327049826,0.9254778402831888,0.17351196302855354,0.09367640725903592,0.13396604033896198,0.10914841113830877,0.13300311344319835,0.06482469796460666,0.2389990283665168,0.9815561616715368,0.0585339857222954,0.1029913122136733,0.0383729277416992,0.5567894776388725,0.6134146295072561,0.7347983990171596,0.22815803680644986,0.06625517496066657,0.6432318583345678,0.350477486526545,0.00766914848441136,0.7292061019449797,0.4632178257158512,0.6006627010366354,0.5728395776931576,0.017667153370483857,0.2303405105534844,0.0187908886556839,0.6365909821132251,0.9104783061047692,0.1029203342000472,0.6403831688172956,0.7465855205007239,0.003865392976895921,0.2503593020249263,0.6168867002392913,0.6396282792884779,0.2228788470910772,0.6836721690332073,0.0442659061149725,0.7260813992742677,0.2256431550018282,0.7423971444962872,0.5420732030080447,0.6082229063270371,0.15021498532867406,0.5763954112737417,0.9562448997898194,0.01835965766730196,0.7632850299025191,0.2335242475397961,0.5696507344737191,0.6168867002392913,0.6414745091063865,0.02091336753369744,0.5356609017609607,0.6610417920664242,0.07078623113142167,0.7032701898177937,0.25451308791402194,0.5696507344737191,0.2503593020249263,0.6955664310284528,0.7889819992518828,0.4760150016815621,0.6952520240115684,0.6253843430408846,0.6526223470334807,0.2446954751769985,0.1029203342000472,0.5487481598077378,0.03174232427735013,0.7423971444962872,0.7260813992742677,0.5780030558939503,0.1168249113256864,0.5005402285906505,0.6385132383595901,0.2076706688812482,0.004316315939731474,0.5527959268847893,0.5344587001464217,0.6432318583345678,0.664107624417183,0.6955664310284528,0.6518720211572341,0.6610417920664242,0.13601825733501338,0.7122381970027803,0.2182816282092908,0.09679576903623588,0.079431946838743,0.602850993855429,0.6483578870935829,0.9044417921388505,0.5379985024270841,0.003865392976895921,0.17862894576004795,0.15602845785559216,0.2200839322453112,0.5957765709194961,0.7149587982038303,0.27223507285738524,0.11712211072188886,0.1699986023944079,0.6385132383595901,0.003865392976895921,0.0339357783868971,0.7099306809960055,0.7347983990171596,0.2524388467725762,0.597211497357959,0.19029625748771886,0.8230571633385037,0.8052154856855146,0.1613740059425931,0.40544716546941817,0.4132580919758583,0.3557667140668689,0.3868045760626755,0.8059056663765753,0.6312147419553418,0.9759952061825568,0.2779800821027445,0.8038196209743722,0.4462973469261713,0.3470616665824344,0.4930905704227292,0.28853339467890426,0.4440792242042712,0.4612833149739976,0.8108159573331793,0.8138524926403706,0.2877975890519804,0.940800121812162,0.33779255347630444,0.4208705490254964,0.9044417921388505,0.4158620153500612,0.811450310187664,0.7762172864476359,0.7762172864476359,0.5509697887919454,0.8438608230292113,0.4584771401383395,0.5128458909672098,0.2779800821027445,0.0383729277416992,0.3916543328339408,0.29914023616450797,0.35204620114657026,0.4206988870402927,0.3739054963377199,0.004316315939731474,0.15602845785559216,0.950432764647012,0.8168237795739175,0.14536679338349956,0.9313927604051444,0.5066061487976794,0.5066270070846124,0.8074777016349168,0.8758499655509144,0.9592659152711264,0.2256431550018282,0.928861116880368,0.7908178960467565,0.664107624417183,0.41790066392462,0.4385115350336168,0.9985920643657608,0.5140073874733813,0.3949563244602505,0.4769741269791264,0.9375334956193044,0.4208705490254964,0.9109157866814735,0.6396282792884779,0.804049979784017,0.5367293158177581,0.41641630343994174,0.8762499512378444,0.9526974245369064,0.5098823263464507,0.845328204457981,0.9275485256257714,0.9340147605115212,0.37738558191917504,0.3306388854002812,0.4164891297845643,0.9325880594136446,0.5180536120793974,0.3700593792872493,0.9121361955118871,0.4925134305864862,0.5069444845804905,0.9066194418957646,0.32753923523701634,0.4112822476041623,0.4156151233911337,0.3260269041301385,0.7154768280461169,0.5040609944840525,0.7727461175738554,0.17351196302855354,0.3335729866372912,0.4760150016815621,0.5051355209796101,0.9841940021065928,0.049226102024943034,0.9254778402831888,0.825034019140545,0.4773188718424243,0.9739683173040382,0.7850630198706505,0.922962276190418,0.9291692672974196,0.3557667140668689,0.3967877671928155,0.9375334956193044,0.2877975890519804,0.9058981014617392,0.4815242576525665,0.376441225801796,0.9114490607449852,0.978339635174936,0.3248014396741529,0.3260269041301385,0.8499340032757063,0.4480476054772825,0.4970723026169613,0.9402573082005578,0.3190950860063675,0.8418040661374,0.41641630343994174,0.7713423036526971,0.28447973530572435,0.2910343083385012,0.02091336753369744,0.35204620114657026,0.2912142352912951,0.8418040661374,0.3850268179369327,0.8770833302660004,0.9915608799859694,0.8543900297391153,0.9815561616715368,0.4632178257158512,0.8636414061448247,0.5128458909672098,0.34443930350760155,0.4952706152372665,0.4697621870079634,0.4158620153500612,0.2779800821027445,0.811450310187664,0.4449509190474525,0.40302759018819656,0.9797409499964082,0.8117633548712893,0.3561841022638447,0.5082217193335185,0.9472812310940384,0.03877962756957088,0.8074777016349168,0.3903889972893888,0.6365909821132251,0.9256379240289082,0.9986798568659072,0.9067898570276643,0.7889819992518828,0.3648521898056963,0.3786684643168372,0.3916543328339408,0.8758499655509144,0.9104783061047692,0.4449509190474525,0.933825494749438,0.4597989153897598,0.2503593020249263,0.2446954751769985,0.5005402285906505,0.3557667140668689,0.9814663917692809,0.4566381750893119,0.4164891297845643,0.3063653634248187,0.4170550221652074,0.825034019140545,0.2785752646205508,0.867061034809968,0.3611266107961518,0.4241271280085879,0.4462973469261713,0.8133441300599541,0.7772832103326837,0.8438608230292113,0.3374279759102293,0.30155627329399204,0.8691034478184957,0.41180130877447785,0.09679576903623588,0.4253730525645958,0.2869456709713616,0.6024113737967441,0.9238719476604618,0.3227335835394828,0.8067403730915316,0.8161086982576026,0.9146103660335191,0.4449509190474525,0.33742624657900044,0.4602563818931488]}}
```

I have the graph with labels showing up but no data is shown. Here is the code I have so far:

```
       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
                let counter = [];
                let answers = ['sensor0', 'sensor1','sensor2','sensor3','sensor4','sensor5','sensor6','sensor7','sensor8','sensor9'];
                $.getJSON('http://0.0.0.0:7410/data', function(data) {
                    // Populate series
                   // console.log(data);

                    //console.log(data.class_label);
                    let arr = []
                    let key;
            for(let event in data){
                let dataCopy = data[event]
                arr.push(dataCopy)
        }




let obj  = (JSON.stringify(arr))
                    console.log(obj);
                    console.log(obj[10]);

                    // draw chart
                    $('#container').highcharts({
                   chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                    title: {
                        text: "Wow"
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: answers,
                        allowDecimals: false,
                        title: {
                            text: ""
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: "Scores"
                        }
                    },
                     series: [{
                        name: 'Subjects',
                         data: arr
                    }]
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try to use data.class_label for your series data if it will render something.

Comment: @jaylordibe I've tried that and commented it out, it prints undefined

Comment: How about your console.log(data)? Do you have an output of that log?

Comment: @jaylordibe that prints out like this which is correct however it looks like an array with an object inside with arrays inside of that object: [{"class_label":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],"sample index": ......

Comment: Try console.log(data[0].class_label);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments - try to get access to the data array like in the demo below.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rjqmoc8s/

```
console.log(receivedData[0]["class_label"])
```